# tabBarController didSelectViewController in AppDelegate is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have used the Xcode tab bar controller template and am trying to detect when a user selects a tab in my tab bar controller. In AppDelegate.h I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

and in AppDelegate.m I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    tabBarController.delegate = self;

    return YES;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"Selected tab bar button!");
}
```

I have not connected any outlets for the Tab Bar Controller scene listed in Main.storyboard because I couldn't figure out the right connection to make, if one is even necessary. I also haven't made any references to this delegate method in my FirstViewController or anywhere else, because the various ways I tried to do that didn't work. Could someone help me understand how to get this working?

Comment: Is the `tabBarController` the `rootViewController` of your app `window`?

Comment: I'm not sure that it is. Let me try to figure out how to check/set that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tab bar controller by selecting `UIViewController`(`FirstViewController` in your case) and choose `Editor` >> `Embed In` >> `Tab Bar Controller`.

Comment: I already have a tab bar controller that switches between two view controllers. Your suggestion creates a second tab bar controller, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the `UITabBarController *tabBarController;` declaration in `AppDelegate.h` (line 4) and replace

```
tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

with

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

in `AppDelegate.m`.

Comment: I did these two things but am still not seeing the  NSLog entry I am trying to call.

Comment: Put `NSLog(@"--> %@", self.tabBarController);` before the `self.tabBarController.delegate = self;` statement.  I suspect that self.tabBarController is nil.  If so, you'll need to link the tabBarController in the storyboard/xib to the reference in `AppDelegate.h` via the Interface Builder.

Comment: You are exactly right, self.tabBarController is (null). Could you be more specific about how to link the tabBarController to AppDelegate.h? Using Assistant Editor view, for example, control-dragging from Tab Bar Controller to AppDelegate.h doesn't seem to do anything. If I right-click on Tab Bar Controller to see outlets I do see "delegate" but also can't seem to drag that to AppDelegate.h.

Comment: You have to double-click on some whitespace in your storyboard to have it focus on the ViewController level.  _Then_, you can control-drag from the tab bar controller to AppDelegate.h in the manner you describe above.

Comment: After double-clicking on white space in the storyboard I'm still not able to control-drag from "Tab Bar Controller" anywhere into AppDelegate.h. I must have something else wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Try deleting (or commenting out) `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;` and try assigning the delegate with `self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController.delegate = self`.  I think you get the reference to the tabbar controller in UIViewController for free.  This is _assuming_ that self.window is set properly.

Comment: Yeah, I was exploring what @n00bProgrammer said and I hadn't set anything for self.window. If I try `[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];` I get a black screen on launch instead of my previously working app. Not sure how to correctly set that...

Comment: Remove (or comment out) `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;` and set the delegate with: `UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.firstObject;  self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController.delegate = self;`

Comment: Doing that I get a warning `unused variable 'window'` and the app crashes on launch with `[AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` in the terminal.

Comment: Then leave your property there (i.e., don't get rid of it).  But, at some point, you must make sure that this property is set.  Perhaps after setting the delegate, you can issue `self.window = window;`.

Comment: That fixed the crash so the app opens normally now, but I'm still getting (null) for self.tabBarController and not seeing the NSLog entry when I use the tabs.

Comment: The bottom line is that those properties you define are not automatically assigned.  You _must_ assign them somewhere if you insist on using them.  I suggest assigning them at the top of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.  Assign them with: `UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.firstObject;    self.window = window;    self.tabBarController = window.rootViewController.tabBarController;`  _Then_, you can assign your delegate with `self.tabBarController = self;`.

Comment: That definitely fixes the (null) problem for self.tabBarController, which now reads `<AppDelegate: 0x7fc3e152d790>`. on `self.tabBarController = self` I am getting a warning `incompatible pointer types assigning to UITabBarController from Appelegate` but the app still runs. Now I just need to get it to call the didSelectViewController method on selecting a tab, which it still isn't doing.

Comment: Sorry, meant `self.tabBarController.delegate = self;`.

Comment: `self.tabBarController.delegate = self;` makes self.tabBarController (null) again but eliminates the `incompatible pointer` warning.

Comment: Did you keep the `self.tabBarController = window.rootViewController.tabBarController;` line?  Please post an update to your question with what you have now.

Comment: I did. The first 4 lines of my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions are 1) `UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.firstObject;` 2) `self.window = window;` 3) `self.tabBarController = window.rootViewController.tabBarController;` 4) `self.tabBarController.delegate = self;`

Comment: Then delete your tabbar controller in your storyboard and add it the way saif suggests.  That may wire it up more properly in your app.  Can you also get the type of `window.rootViewController`?

Comment: I deleted the tab bar controller and add it back, making sure to embed the FirstViewController. Everything runs fine, but I'm still not able to call the didSelectViewController method. When I use NSLog to see the rootViewController in AppDelegate I get `UITabBarController`. After deleting and re-adding I tried control-dragging the tab bar controller into AppDelegate.h but am still not able to.